# libreoffice calc: formatting hyperlinks

Tags: libreoffice

My installation of libreoffice calc 5.1.1.3 doesn't seem to alter the formatting of hyperlinks, i.e. it looks the same as any other text by default.

When doing searches for how to format said links, I seem to see two advices reappear:

1. go to options->libreoffice->appearance and change something.
2. bring up the 'styles and formatting' window and click the 'character styles' tab.

Except the appearance submenu and the character styles tab don't seem to exist anymore, and I can't find anything equivalent.

What is a current, up-to-date way of changing the automatic formatting of hyperlinks?

EDIT: here are some images showing the problem--as per settings, the black link should appear blue?

[image: hyperlink fail]

[image: colorsettings]

Answer (score 7):

The solution depends on **how the hyperlinks are created**. There are two ways to generate a hyperlink in Calc:

1. Menu `Insert` -> `Hyperlink`
2. using the [**`HYPERLINK()`**](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#HYPERLINK) function.

In the *first* case, LO Calc inserts a field.

In the *second* case, the result is "plain text" with additional functionality if the user clicks on the hyperlink text.

## Formatting a "text hyperlink"

Formatting a "text hyperlink" (created using the `HYPERLINK()` function) works the same way as formatting any other text content: using direct formatting - applying text style properties directly using the toolbar or Menu `Format` -> `Text`; or using cell styles.

[image]

## Formatting a "field hyperlink"

Formatting a "field hyperlink" (created using Menu Insert -> Hyperlink) is somewhat more complicated, but it has the advantage that LO will apply a certain styling by default:

The actual design of "field hyperlinks" in Calc is the result of two settings: Field shading, and link color. You can't set the link color on a per-document basis, instead changes are applied application-wide (will affect hyperlinks in writer, too).

### LibreOffice <= 5.0.x.x:

To modify the "field hyperlink" link color (and in calc, the link background -> field shading):

Menu `Tools` -> `Options` -> `LibreOffice` -> `Appearance`. Search for "`unvisited links`" or "`visited links`", and change the color:

[image]

For the field background in Calc, scroll down to the `Text Document` section (!), and change the "`field shadings`" setting.

### LibreOffice >= 5.1.x.x:

To modify the link color (and in calc, the link background -> field shading):
Menu `Tools` -> `Options` -> `LibreOffice` -> `Application Colors`. Search for "`Unvisited links`" or "`Visited links`", and change the color:

[image]

For the field background in Calc, scroll down to the `Text Document` section (!), and change the "`Field Shadings`" setting.

Important:

Take care to tick the checkboxes at the left of the setting name (in the second screenshot: marked with red rectangle).

Important, too:

Don't apply magenta to hyperlinks, as in the second screenshoot - looks extremely ugly...

<sup>*(LO 5.1.x: Tested with both Linux x86_64 and Windows 10)*</sup>

Comment: As I said in the OP, the "appearance" submenu doesn't exist in the libreoffice version I'm using.  It seems to have been moved to 'application colours'.  http://s31.postimg.org/4vbdd4rp7/appcolors.png  These settings don't seem to be taking effect--hyperlinks look like black text.

Comment: I made a new empty spreadsheet, added in a hyperlink and captured the problem in action, added the images to the OP.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way of having the formatting occur automatically for all hyperlink text.  I'm also wondering what the practical reason is for having two ways of inserting links (seems the field way just has less flexibility).

Comment: @RobF: The "field" hyperlinks should work in every LO component (you can have hyperlinks in writer, impress and so on, too). The HYPERLINK() function may be added for compatibility reasons to other Spreadsheet software. Also, it allows for dynamic hyperlinks (based on other  spreadsheet values). If you want LO to format your hyperlinks in a coherent way, you should use the "field" hyperlinks, esp. if the link target is static.

Comment: It's dynamic, hence the problem.

Comment: I am using Version: LO v6.2.2.2 and for a reason that I cannot explain the 'field shading' configuration on the hyperlinks is not taken any more into consideration!

Comment: Is there a way to format a "text hyperlink" taking into account if the link has been clicked or not? just how regular links behavie

Comment: https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=66545 , formatting of links changed in LibreOffice 6.2